# Debugging : Mergesort

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, mergesort

Trying to implement merge sort in Java. I've gone over my code a bunch in my head and I feel like it should be working, but obviously I'm doing something wrong. Heres the code

```
    public static void mergeSort(int[] input, int start, int end) {
        if (end - start < 2)
            return;
        
        int mid = (start + end) / 2;
        mergeSort(input, start, mid);
        mergeSort(input, mid + 1, end);
        merge(input, start, mid, end);
    }

    public static void merge(int[] input, int start, int mid, int end) {
        if (input[mid - 1] <= input[mid])
            return;
         
        int i = start;
        int j = mid;
        int tempIndex = 0;
        int[] temp = new int[end - start]; //combined size of both arrays being merged
        
        /*if i is >= mid, then that means the left portion of the array is done being sorted
          and vice versa if j >= end. Once this happens, we should be able to
          just copy the remaining elements into the temp array 
        */
        while (i < mid && j < end) {
            temp[tempIndex++] = (input[i] <= input[j]) ? input[i++] : input[j++];
        }
        
        //Copying left over elements in left portion
        while (i < mid)
            temp[tempIndex++] = input[i++];
        
        //Copying left over elements in right portion
        while (j < end)
            temp[tempIndex++] = input[j++];
        
        //Copy the sorted temp array into the original array
        //This is where I think I must be messing up
        for (int k = 0; k < temp.length; k++) {
            input[start + k] = temp[k];    
        }
     }
```

I think it must be that im not copying correctly the temp array with the sorted elements back into the original array, but I'm not sure. I wrote comments on my code explaining my logic.

Comment: What was the result of **YOUR** debugging attempts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the following changes:

1. Calculating mid

   > int mid = start + (end - start) / 2;
2. Assigning pointers i,j correctly.

   > int i = start;
   > int j = mid+1;
3. Correct size of temp array.

   > int [] temp = new int[end-start+1];
4. Corrected while loops condition in the code.

   ```
    class Solution{

    public static void mergeSort(int[] input, int start, int end) 
    {
        if (end == start ) return;

        int mid = start + (end - start) / 2;
        mergeSort(input, start, mid);
        mergeSort(input, mid+1, end);
        merge(input, start, mid, end);
    }

     public static void merge(int[] input, int start, int mid, int end) {
        // No Need of the under mentioned instruction
        // if(input[mid-1] <= input[mid]) return;

        int i = start;
        int j = mid+1;
        int tempIndex = 0;
        int [] temp = new int[end-start+1]; //combined size of both arrays being merged

        /*if i is >= mid, then that means the left portion of the array is done being sorted and vice versa if j >= end. Once this happens, we should be able to just copy the remaining elements into the temp array */

        while(i <= mid && j <= end){
            temp[tempIndex++] = (input[i] <= input[j]) ? input[i++] : input[j++];
        }

        //Copying left over elements in left portion
        while(i <= mid)
            temp[tempIndex++] = input[i++];

        //Copying left over elements in right portion
        while(j <= end)
            temp[tempIndex++] = input[j++];

        //Copy the sorted temp array into the original array
        //This is where I think I must be messing up
        for(int k = 0; k < temp.length; k++){
            input[start+k] = temp[k];    
        }
     }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] input = {9,4,6,8,5,7,0,2};
        mergeSort(input,0,7);

        for(int i : input)
            System.out.println(i);    
    }

    }
   ```

Comment: How come you added 1 to j and 1 to the size of the temp array?

Comment: @cris Because array for j starts from mid+1. if start = 2 and end = 5 then total number of elements will be 4(2,3,4,5). That's why I have added 1 to start - end.